# Relation between two texts with different tags

Tags: algorithm

I'm currently having a problem with the conception of an algorithm.
I want to create a WYSIWYG editor that goes along the current [bbcode] editor I have.

To do that, I use a `div` with `contenteditable` set to true for the WYSIWYG editor and a `textarea` containing the associated bbcode. Until there, no problem. But my concern is that if a user wants to add a tag (for example, the `[b]` tag), I need to know where they want to include it.

For that, I need to know exactly where in the bbcode I should insert the tags. I thought of comparing the two texts (one with html tags like `<span>`, the other with bbcode tags like `[b]`), and that's where I'm struggling.

I did some research but couldn't find anything that would help me, or I did not understand it correctly (maybe did I do a wrong research). What I could find is the `Jaccard index`, but I don't really know how to make it work correctly.

I also thought of another alternative. I could just take the code in the WYSIWYG editor before the cursor location, and split it every time I encounter a html tag. That way, I can, in the bbcode editor, search for the first occurrence, then search for the second occurrence starting at the last index found, and so on until I reach the place where the cursor is pointing at.

I'm not sure if it would work, and I find that solution a bit dirty. Am I totally wrong or should I do it this way?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

A popular way of determining what is the level of the similarity between the two texts is computing the mentioned Jaccard similarity. Citing Wikipedia:

*The Jaccard index, also known as Intersection over Union and the Jaccard similarity coefficient, is a statistic used for comparing the similarity and diversity of sample sets. The Jaccard coefficient measures the similarity between finite sample sets, and is defined as the size of the intersection divided by the size of the union of the sample sets:*
[image]
[image]

If you have a large number of texts though, computing the full Jaccard index of every possible combination of two texts is super computationally expensive. There is another way to approximate this index that is called **minhashing**. What it does is use several (e.g. 100) independent hash functions to create a signature and it repeats this procedure many times. This whole process has a nice property that the probability (over all permutations) that T1 = T2 is the same as J(A,B).

Another way to cluster similar texts (or any other data) together is to use **Locality Sensitive Hashing** which by itself is an approximation of what KNN does, and is usually worse than that, but is definitely faster to compute. The basic idea is to project the data into low-dimensional binary space (that is, each data point is mapped to a N-bit vector, the hash key). Each hash function *h* must satisfy the sensitive hashing property *prob[h(x)=h(y)]=sim(x,y)* where *sim(x,y) in [0,1]* is the similarity function of interest. For dots products it can be visualized as follows:

[image]
we can now ask what would be the has of the indicated point (in this case it's 101) and everything that is close to this point has the same hash.

**EDIT to answer the comment**
No, you asked about the text similarity and so I answered that. You basically ask how can you predict the position of the character in text 2. It depends on whether you analyze the writer's style or just pure syntax. In any of those two cases, IMHO you need some sort of statistics that will tell where it is likely for this character to occur given all the other data/text. You can go with n-grams, RNNs, LSTMs, Markov Chains or any other form of sequential data analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess I'll dig it this way. But I know both texts are similar, I just want to know where the character at index x in text 1 will be in text 2. Will the solution fit for that ?

Comment: I didn't really ask about text similarity: I know the two texts are equivalent. The only difference is that bbcode is converted to html tags. I don't need to analyse the writer's style, that's the exact same text. I need to know where the character at position x in text 1 will be in text 2, given that text 1 is the html code and text 2 is the bbcode, and I cannot unprocess text 1 to get text 2.

Comment: I don't even know what language you're using but there's a python package that can do what you want https://pypi.org/project/html2bbcode/2.3.2/